# Integrate CKEditor5 Document type with Salesforce Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, ckeditor5, lwc

I have been trying different ways to use the CKEditor5 inside a Salesforce Visualforce page. The Editor loads ok, but the document style doesn't come up in the expected format. Also, when I type anything in editing space, there are bunch of errors in the console.

Has anyone successfully integrated CKEditor5 inside Salesforce Visualforce page and use that in an Experience Cloud site?

The steps I followed were;

- Created a CKEditor5 build using the online builder
- Upload that into a Salesforce static resource.
- Used that static library in Visualforce page, create an editor instance.